# Como Direcionar comandos para o terminal Linux com Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Preciso criar um script em Phyton que quando executado seja via 'click' do mouse ou 'enter' do teclado, ele próprio abra o terminal linux e execute um comando qualquer dentro do mesmo. Já consegui fazer com que ele execute o comando, mas desde que o script seja executado já dentro do terminal.

Já tentei de tudo o que estava ao meu alcance via google, tentei usar os.system(), subprocess(), mas nenhum resolveu.
 Meu código nesse momento é o seguinte:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding; utf-8 -*-


import subprocess

processo = subprocess.Popen(args = ['pantheon-terminal'],
                     stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                     shell = True)

processo.communicate('ls') # Aqui um erro
```

Ele deveria abrir o terminal e executar o comando ls, mas apenas abre o terminal.

Edit:
 Como podem ver acima, eu estava usando processo.communicate('ls'), ou seja, estava passando o comando de forma errada, mas ainda não sei onde por o comando para ele ser executado dentro do terminal que foi aberto pelo script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding; utf-8 -*-

import subprocess

processo = subprocess.call(["ls", "-la"], shell=True)
#seria o mesmo que ls -la no seu terminal.
```

Veja os detalhes em:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Answer (score 1):

Por partes:

1. O que vai acontecer ao se clicar no seu script depende do que está
   configurando para ser feito no gerenciador de janelas.
2. Presumindo que o script vá ser executado: o interpretador python não
   tem uma interface gráfica, logo, ele sempre vai abrir em um terminal,
   mas o ambiente dentro do python pode ser diferente do
   ambiente puro e simples do seu emulador de terminal, por exemplo:
   Se, ao abrir um terminal ele vai estar no diretório /home/usuario e
   o comando xyz funciona, dentro do python é outra história. Pode ser necessário entrar no diretório em questão e adicionar o caminho do comando xyz ao PATH.
3. Se um terminal é aberto apenas para executar um programa sem
   interface gráfica, ele vai ser fechado assim que o programa
   terminar. Para evitar isso, usando python, você pode adicionar uma
   pausa no final do seu script [exemplo1] ou esperar que o usuário digite enter [exemplo2].
4. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29846/como-chamar-comando-externo-com-python/30740#30740) deixei uma pequena classe para ajudar na execução de comandos, acho-a bem útil!

[exemplo1]

```
from time import sleep
sleep(5)
```

[exemplo2]

```
raw_input('Presione enter para sair')
```

Nota: Os itens 1 e 2 não parecem ser o seu problema atualmente, os citei porque acredito que possam vir a ser.